# Jasper report artifact always corrupted

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project that depend on the following artifact to my maven repository:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperserver-common-ws</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jaspersoft.api.metadata</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperserver-api-metadata</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperserver-ireport-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

when i run maven install eclipse output a warning  specify that check-sum validation
failed. when i try to open the installed jar using winrar , win-rar indicate that they are corrupted. I have tried to turn off antivirus yet the artifact are still fail to download properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have too many `dependencies` ?

Just add this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This should be enough to run your `JasperReport.`

Comment: is 5.5.0 backward compatible with 5.0.1, actually i am not familiar with jasper report i am just mavenizing the project.

Comment: It should be. LIke Java 7 has to be backward compatible with 1.4